# Is their any Age limit to become a Buddha?

Tags: the-buddha, buddhas

we all know Prince Siddartha, about 29 years old when he began his quest for enlightenment. His quest was accomplished about six years later, when he was in his mid-30s became Lord Buddha. so my question is, is their any Age limit to become a Buddha?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such age or age limit. For example,  Kassapa Buddha, the sixth of the Seven Buddhas of Antiquity, and the third of the five Buddhas of the present kalpa practiced austerities for only seven days. Kassapa Budda attained Parinibbhana at the age of forty thousand years. At that time children would get married at the age of 500 according to legend.